# CentOS live webserver access

Tags: linux, centos

I have a question regarding CentOS as it's the system my server runs. I user HTOP to look over the CPU and memory usage on my server. The server has several webpages attached to it and i was wondering if it is possible to se what pages are accessed on the server live, just like the 300 latest pages in Cpanel only i want to se this live and not have to update the page to se the new pages accessed, is this possible in either htop or any other program that can be run on CentOS ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see live which page is accessed just do a *tail* to your logfile (ex.)

```
tail -f /your/path/to/logfile.log
```

Comment: Yes, i have to type this command each time but i want it running live without me doing anything as i want to have the ssh window with this on another monitor.

Comment: It's running as long as you want until you send CTRL+c.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement about "live" correctly:

use tmux and leave it running in the background. you can attach to it any time you need to look at it. so it's always "running live" as long as the server is up.